# Разделение объектов на "просмотренные" и "не просмотренные"

Tags: android

Есть список лотов. 
Лоты бывают: все, просмотренные и непросмотренные.
Из первой таблицы БД тяну все лоты. 
Из второй таблицы БД тяну просмотренные. 
В интеракторе буду делать List по принципу сначала непросмотренные потом просмотренные.
Список буду передавать в Recycler где есть два типа viewHoldera.

Вопрос: как реализовать разделение лотов? У лота не может быть булеан поля isVisited. 
Создаю прокси класс для просмотренных лотов. Наследую его от класса обычного лота. В Recycler использую instance of. 
годный вариант или есть поинтересней решение?

Comment: У лота не может быть булеан поля isVisited, это ваша фишка, что его не может быть ?  Так все и решается самый быстрый, простой и правильный способ. Когда из базы вытаскиваете можете выставлять. Играя инстесами вы набьете шишку, простая ситуация вы захотите непросмотренный сделать просмотренным динамически.

Comment: Не моя воля. увы((

Уже просмотренные обернул в отдельный класс. Если надо сделать просмотренный сделать не просмотренным, то:
1. во второй таблице затереть лот
2. рефреш дата.